# Runtime error in codeshef atm problem python

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, python-3.9

I wrote a solution for codechef's atm problem and got runtime error but in my computer it worked well.

Question - https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST/

My code

```
withdraw, balance = input().split()
print(balance if (int(withdraw)>=float(balance) or int(withdraw) %5 !=0) else float(balance) - int(withdraw) - 0.50 )
```

Error

```
NZEC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this thread, you need to provide custom input when clicking 'run'. The test cases will only be run when you click 'submit'.

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/python-error-while-taking-input/21416

From the thread:

> If you are trying to run the code in IDE mode then you must provide
> custom input, otherwise you will get NZEC. This is the only reason you
> are getting this error. If you wanna submit then just submit. So RUN
> and SUBMIT both are different functionalities. In case of SUBMIT,
> codechef gives it’s test cases. But in case of RUN, you should give
> input.